# What keeps the sugar suspended in the tea?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

At room temperature....

How long will the sugar stay suspended once dissolved ?

What governs the rate of settling ?

What part does Brownian motion play ?

*Sugar might be a bad example...please substitute as needed.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything dissolved is kept "suspended" by brownian motion. 
Theoreticly there will be a small gradient of concentration 
due to gravity, but this is unmeasurable for sugar. 
(Barometric formula). For much bigger particles (ãbout µm) , this 
gradient can be determined.

The sugar will stay dissolved until the water evaporates,
then the sugar will form a solid residue. (if You are lucky, 
as crystals) Settling does not occur with molecules.

Comment: I'd like to see an explicit mention of entropy vs internal energy, and a bit more thermodynamics in the answer, rather than just a microscopically detailed mechanical description.

Comment: @ genneth, Feel free to write an answer including entropy.